# status_of_proc does not find the process

Tags: debian, init-script

I am trying to make an init script to work as expected, the start / stop functionalities works flawlessly, but I cannot get the status function to work as expected.
I am running :
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.6 (wheezy)
Release:        7.6
Codename:       wheezy

Here is my init script :

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          graylog-collector
# Required-Start:    $network $named $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $network $named $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Graylog Collector
# Description:       Graylog's open source log shipper
### END INIT INFO

# Process name ( For display )
NAME="graylog-collector"
# Daemon name, where is the actual executable
DAEMON="/etc/graylog-collector/bin/graylog-collector"
# DAEMON args
DAEMON_OPT="run -f /etc/graylog-collector/config/collector.conf"
# User to run the deamon
DAEMON_USER="graylog-collector"
# pid file for the daemon
PIDDIR="/var/run/$NAME"
PIDFILE="$PIDDIR/$NAME.pid"


PATH="/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

. /lib/lsb/init-functions




d_start () {
    log_daemon_msg "Starting system $NAME Daemon"
    if [ ! -e $PIDDIR ] ; then
            mkdir $PIDDIR
            chown ${DAEMON_USER}:${DAEMON_USER} $PIDDIR
    fi
    start-stop-daemon --background --start \
            --user $DAEMON_USER \
            --chuid $DAEMON_USER \
            --make-pidfile \
            --pidfile $PIDFILE \
            --startas /bin/bash -- -c "exec $DAEMON $DAEMON_OPT >> /var/log/graylog-collector/console.log 2>&1" || return 2
    sleep 2
    log_end_msg $?
}

d_stop () {
    log_daemon_msg "Stopping system $NAME Daemon"
    start-stop-daemon --stop --retry 5 --quiet --user $DAEMON_USER
    rm -f $PIDFILE
    log_end_msg $?
}

case "$1" in

    start|stop)
            d_${1}
            ;;

    restart|reload|force-reload)
                    d_stop
                    d_start
            ;;

    force-stop)
            d_stop
            killall -q $NAME || true
            sleep 2
            killall -q -9 $NAME || true
            ;;

    status)
            status_of_proc "${PIDFILE}" "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?
            ;;
    *)
            echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/$NAME {start|stop|force-stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status}"
            exit 1
            ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Thank you.

***Update 1 :***
I updated the script with an ugly but working solution (at least for my little requirements), by creating this function :

```
do_status () {

        if { ps -U ${DAEMON_USER} ; } >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then

                log_success_msg "${NAME} is running"

                return 0

        else

                log_failure_msg "${NAME} is not running"

                return $?

        fi

}
```

Then calling it :

```
status)
                    #status_of_proc "${PIDFILE}" "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0     || exit $?
                    do_status
                    ;;
```

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding you should have used -p with "${PIDFILE}". That said unless you used "set -e", which you should never do in an init.d script checking the process with -p doesn't work I think. In the end try this instead:

```
status)
    status_of_proc "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?
    ;;
```